# Query issue using Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

My query looks like this :

```
SELECT parent2.subid AS parent2id, parent2.sub AS parent2desc,
key.subid AS ID, parent1.subid AS parentid, 
parent1.sub AS parentdesc, key.sub AS key 
FROM (table1 AS key LEFT JOIN table1 AS parent1 ON key.parent_id=parent1.subid)
LEFT JOIN table1 AS parent2 
ON parent1.parent_id=parent2.subid into Query_table
```

This query when run on the dB without the `into Query_table` works fine, but I want to create the table dynamically and perform some operations.

In the above query I get the following error:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in
>   query expression
>   'parent1.parent_id=parent2.subid into
>   Query_tabl'"

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `INTO` clause comes between the select list and the `FROM` clause. I.e.

```
select .... INTO Query_table FROM ...
```